# How do I deploy a corporate React-Native app to employees of company?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I was hired by an engineering firm to make an Employee Login and Timesheet app for iOS and Android, which I am using React-Native to achieve. I have to integrate the Front-End to an existing database (with Employee table, Client table, etc.) on SQL server 2008.

Obviously, I don't want this thing anywhere near the app store to allow anyone access to private company information. How am I to deploy the app to the company's employees when it's complete?

Comment: Have you managed to get this done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them pay for the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/), or use something like [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/).

Comment: I think since they need both the iOS and Android versions, the HockeyApp would work perfectly fine. As long as everyone can get a copy of my app on their phone, things will be peachy. Much appreciated!

Comment: These are two different things. HockeyApp is a distribution channel. Enterprise Build is how you build it. You are able to use HockeyApp to distribute an enterprise build too. But without enterprise build every user of your app has to tell hockey his device id until you reach the limit of 100 devices. So if your company has less than 90 devices (e.g. 10 for testing the app) it's ok. But if not you need the enterprise build too.

Comment: There is also a business solution called Volume Purchase Program (VPP). In that case you develop your app and distribute it via App Store (including apple review) but its only available for a limited user range. I haven't used it in my projects but its the official apple solution for business app distribution. Maybe you should take a look into it.